# Receiving alerts for GCP activities

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to create alerts for configuration activities?

On the dashboard of my GCP project, I'm able to see the history of activities. However, for security reasons, I would like to be able to receive notifications when certain activities happen, e.g. Set IAM policy on project, deleting instance of project, etc. Is this possible?

I have looked into "metric-based alerting policies", but I'm only able to create alerts for uptime checks. Not sure what else to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. You need to [create a log-based metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) and then to [create an alert when the counter](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#alert-on-lbm) cross a threshold (1 for example)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It feels like I just discovered a whole new world with the "log-based metrics" option.

Answer (score 1):

Now a more straightforward solution is available: In one step, you can use [log-based alerts](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/alerting/log-based-alerts). It allows to set alerts on any log type and content. This new feature is on preview and was [announced few days ago.](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/operations/create-logs-alerts-preview)